# Animating 2 separate items with JQuery and pausing both on mouseover

Tags: jquery

http://nerotic.net/auxout/

I've been going a little batty with this problem. On the map I have a series of dots that have two actions assigned to them:

```
onmouseover : pops up a tooltip
click: changes the content in the panel on the right
```

The page is set to auto play through the items that populate the left panel.

What I'd like to do is have the corresponding tooltips highlight in unison with the left panel.

And then, I'd like both to completely stop when the user mouses over any dot on the map.

I've been very frustrated, my javascript knowledge is rather weak and I keep barking up the wrong tree even though I've made decent progress.

I just have a feeling that I'm not going about this the right way, if anyone could offer me a little guidance I'd be appreciative.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
                   $(document).ready(function() { 
                   jcps.fader(100, '#switcher-panel'); 

                   setTimeout("callCity('#la')",2000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#mexico')",4000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#ny')",6000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#singapore')",8000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#australia')",10000);
                   setTimeout("callCity('#france')",12000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#england')",14000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#spain')",16000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#canada')",18000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#chicago')",20000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#minn')",22000);  
                   setTimeout("callCity('#stpaul')",24000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#dallas')",26000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#boston')",28000); 
                   setTimeout("callCity('#arizona')",30000); 
                   }); 
                    function callCity(city) 
                    { 
                    $(city).trigger('click'); 
                    } 
                    $('#berlin').mousedown(function() {
              alert('Handler for .mousedown() called.');
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: You should post some code in order to get more help.

Comment: Thanks Moin...I went back to some of my older posts and accepted those answers which helped me best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A buddy of mine helped me sort this out...here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                   $(document).ready(function() {
                   jcps.fader(100, '#switcher-panel');
                   var timeouts = new Array();
                   var cities = ["#la", "#mexico", "#ny", "#singapore", "#australia", "#italy", "#france", "#england", "#spain", "#canada", "#chicago", "#minn", "#stpaul", "#dallas", "#boston", "#berlin", "#arizona"];
                   var timeoutLength = 3400;
                   for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++)
                   {
                       timeouts[i] = setTimeout("callCity('" + cities[i] +"')", timeoutLength * (i + 1));
                   }
                       $('.switcher').mouseover(function() {
                          for( key in timeouts )
                          {  
                            clearTimeout(timeouts[key]);  
                             }
                           });
                   });
                   function callCity(city)
                    {
                    $(city).trigger('click');
                    }
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question but this might help

```
$('.animate').each(function() {

    $(this).animate({height: '600px'}, 10000);
});

$('.animate').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({width: '600px'}, 10000);
});

$('.stop').mouseover(function() {

    $('.animate').stop();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KXLBV/

Comment: thanks for the idea but it's very different than what I was trying to accomplish. I'm posting the solution that's worked for me now.